# Extreme Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

In Excel, I have a Pivot Table on one worksheet that is doing a count formula from another worksheet called "All".  On a third worksheet (we'll this one "Servers"), I have a list of IP Addresses they are conditionally formatted based on their location.  I use the Servers sheet to do Advanced Filtering on the All sheet.

What I am hoping to do is conditionally format the Pivot Table columns based on the Server's formatting on the Server sheet.  It will probably require a macro, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: The environment information is in a column next to the server IP.

Answer (score 0):

You could have one pivot table per location (with each it's own formatting), and depending what is the location of the server you want to print, you pick the value from a specific table.

It would be a quick way to do it, and it’s kind of clean I guess.

I wouldn’t know [on the top of my head] how to do this, without macro.

Comment: I'm not married to the idea of no macro.